# How do I properly write a question that involves third-party libraries?

Tags: support, asking-questions, third-party

I am preparing to submit a small OpenGL program for review. I've included some source files from [this](https://github.com/tomdalling/opengl-series) GitHub repo to handle some image stuff I don't want to deal with. I'm not asking for a review of these files, but they are necessary to build the program. So the project structure is something like

```
- main.cpp <- Mine
- Drawable.cpp/Drawable.h <- Mine
- Bitmap.cpp/Bitmap.h <- Taken unedited from GitHub
```

So what needs to happen in the question body? Is it enough to say, e.g. "I use Bitmap.* and platform* from the tdogl library. The files can be found at this link."?

Comment: To be clear, you have files a, b, and c that you've edited. You have files d, e and f that you've unedited right? You're asking how you should ask your question?

Comment: @Peilonrayz There are just files that I've written, and unedited files that someone else wrote. I edited to try to clarify.

Comment: Ok so you have files `A` that you wrote 100% yourself. And you require files `B` that someone else wrote. There are no files `C` that you've modified from someone else's code?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bare minimum to post a question is to include some code.

If you were to post a question that only included `main.cpp`, but not `Drawable.cpp` or `Drawable.h`, and didn't mention anything about this `Bitmap.cpp`, then it'd be on-topic, but a really poor question (as we don't know what half the code is).

---

Building from this, you can include the code you want, and explain that a certain import comes from another library. Take:

> **Note**: The code in the module `.bitmap` is not my code and is [available for download here]. Name it `bitmap.py`.
>
> `main.py`
>
> ```
> from .bitmap import external_code
> from .drawable import my_code
>
> external_code(my_code(...))
> ```
>
> `drawable.py`
>
> ```
> ...
> ```

This way, you've included your own code, and you've provided the external code that others can use to work with yours correctly, making it a good question.